# Monitor settings not persisting across reboot

Tags: display, config.txt

I have two monitors connected to a RPi 4B rev 1.4 running Raspbian 10. When I boot, both monitors are mirrored, so I go to Preferences > Screen Configuration and set the monitors up how I want (side-by-side). However, when I reboot again, the monitors are back to mirrored mode.

How can I get these settings to persist?

I have already confirmed that in `/boot/config.txt`, `max_framebuffers=2` is set, per some other SE posts.

This is particularly strange because I have gotten this to work with a different pair of monitors in the past, with the same Raspberry Pi, and no software changes in the ensuing time period. The old monitors were one HDMI & one DVI (through an HDMI-to-DVI cable); the new monitors are both HDMI. Perhaps the HDMI monitors are talking back to the Pi and somehow requesting to be mirrored?

If this is helpful, per `xrandr --listmonitors` my two monitors are:

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*HDMI-1 1920/476x1080/268+1920+0  HDMI-1
 1: +HDMI-2 1920/477x1080/268+0+0  HDMI-2
```

and `tvservice -l` says:

```
2 attached device(s), display ID's are : 
Display Number 2, type HDMI 0
Display Number 7, type HDMI 1
```

This is after I have changed the monitors to be how I want them. After a reboot, `tvservice` says the same thing, but `xrandr` says

```
Monitors: 2
 0: +*HDMI-1 1920/476x1080/268+0+0  HDMI-1
 1: +HDMI-2 1920/477x1080/268+0+0  HDMI-2
```

however this is the same besides the offset on HDMI-1.

Is the best thing to do just to put an `xrandr` command in some rc or boot file? Or is there a way I can actually get these settings to persist on a per-monitor basis, as I'd expect?

Thanks!